# ¿Estructura de la base de datos de Instagram en Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Quiero recrear la estructura de la base de datos de Instagram en Firebase.

Para ello, utilizo el ejemplo de Posts de Google como ejemplo:

**- Estructura de Usuarios:**
Colección donde guardamos los datos de un usuario, existen los usuarios con ID "U-001" y "U-002"

**- Estructura de Posts:**
Colección donde guardamos los datos de un post, existe el post "P-001" creado por "U-001" y el post "P-002" creado por la usuaria "U-002". Un post puede tener un numero de estrellas que indican a que usuarios les ha gustado el post.

[image: estructura_de_users_yposts]

**- Estructura de Lista de Posts:**
Colección que define la lista de posts a mostrar en la app, en el caso de Instagram, la ventana principal donde vemos la lista de publicaciones (las fotos) de los usuarios a los que seguimos, en la lista solo mostraremos el titulo de cada post.

- El usuario "U-001" ve el post que ha creado y el post de la usuaria a la que sigue "U-002".
- En cambio, la usuaria "U-002" no sigue a nadie por lo que solo ve el post que ha creado.

[image: estructura_de_list_posts]

.
.
.

Imaginemos que la usuaria "U-002" tiene 100 millones de seguidores.

Esto hace que cuando la usuaria "U-002" publique un nuevo *post*, tenga que escribir en cada lista (*list_posts*) de cada usuario que le hace *follower* para que este sea notificado o cuando este abra la aplicación se le cargue el nuevo *post* de "U-002".

Esto cuando son un numero pequeño de seguidores no pasa nada, pero cuando se tienen 100 millones de seguidores, en Firebase tengo que hacer una consulta para obtener esos 100 millones de IDs de usuarios, y escribir en cada *list_post* de cada uno de esos usuarios y añadir el post que crea la usuaria "U-002"?

Me parece absurdo, son muchos megas que se descargan, muchos que se suben... etc para realizar esa función.

Answer (score 2):

Richi,

Como lo planteas, tener una referencia de cada post en la lista de cada follower no es escalable. Lo ideal sería simplemente mantener un listado de los seguidores (para cada usuario) y en el momento que el usuario postea, notificar a todos sus seguidores.

Una recomendación sería utilizar [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/), que te permite extender la lógica de los servicios de Firebase utilizando javascript en el mismo ambiente serverless en el que corren dichos servicios. De esa manera podrías definir por ejemplo una función que se llame cada vez que se cree un post y envíe una notificación a todos sus seguidores, sin tener que hacer modificaciones en la BD ni descargas.